# How can I update a Custom View Model using ASP MVC with DbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a db model for which I would like to edit with multiple Views. My actual db model is much larger than what I'm showing here.

**Db Model:** *PersonModel*

```cs
public class PersonModel {
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I then have two Views, *EditPersonName.cshtml* and *EditPersonDescription.cshtml* that enable the user to modify different parts of the *PersonModel*.

**View 1:** *EditPersonName.cshtml*

```cs
@model EditPersonNameModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)</div>
<div class="editor-field">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)</div>
<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)</div>
<div class="editor-field">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)</div>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

**View 2:** *EditPersonDescription.cshtml*

```cs
@model EditPersonDescriptionModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description)</div>
<div class="editor-field">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description)</div>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Rather than have each view tied directly to *PersonModel*, I'm wanting link them to *EditPersonNameModel* and *EditPersonDescriptionModel*, respectively.

**View Model 1:** *EditPersonNameModel*

```cs
public class EditPersonNameModel {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model 2:** *EditPersonDescriptionModel*

```cs
public class EditPersonDescriptionModel {
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I suppose it's also worth mentioning that I'm using EF's *DbContext* pattern.

```cs
public class PersonDbContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<PersonModel> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Now for my controller, which is where things start to break!

**Controller:** *PersonController*

```cs
public class PersonController {
    private PersonDbContext = new PersonDbContext();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditName(int id) {
        // ??? ---- #1 -----
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditName(EditPersonNameModel model, int id) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            // ??? ---- #2 ----- ??? Update FirstName,LastName ONLY
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditDescription(int id) {
        // ??? ---- #3 -----
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditDescription(EditPersonDescriptionModel model, int id) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            // ??? ---- #4 ----- ??? Update Description ONLY
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }

}
```

My problem is that I don't know what to put in the `??? ---- #X -----` blocks above. Obviously `#1` and `#3` are going to be very similar, as are `#2` and `#4`.

Some have suggested that I use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper). That helps going from the Db Model to the View Model, but not the other way around.

Presently my code block for `#1` looks like this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditName(int id) {
    PersonModel person = db.Persons.Find(id);
    if (person == null) {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    EditPersonNameModel viewModel;
    AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<PersonModel, EditPersonNameModel>();
    viewModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<PersonModel, EditPersonNameModel>(person);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And my code block for `#2` looks like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditName(EditPersonNameModel viewModel, int id) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        PersonModel person = db.Persons.Find(id);
        if (person == null) {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        EditPersonNameModel viewModel;
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<EditPersonNameModel, PersonModel>();
        person = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<EditPersonNameModel, PersonModel>(viewModel);
        db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

`#1` above actually works fine. AutoMapper will map from the larger Person object to the EditPersonName object.

`#2` above, however, is broken. AutoMapper will map from EditPersonNameModel object to **a new** Person object and thus `db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified` will throw an exception:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

I don't need AutoMapper to create a new object, I need to to map to an **existing** object. If only there were `AutoMapper.Mapper.`**Update**`<EditPersonNameModel, PersonModel>(viewModel, person)`.

Ok, so this is now a very LONG question! Thank you for reading and I really appreciate your help! If you are familiar with AutoMapper and know that I'm doing something wrong, please let me know. If you read this code and know of a different way to do this altogether, please let me know that too!

Thank you!!!

---

**Update 1**

I have a `#2` working, but I'm not sure how good it is.

New `#2`

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditName(EditPersonNameModel viewModel, int id) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        PersonModel person = db.Persons.Find(id);
        if (person == null) {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        TryUpdateModel(person);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Note that `TryUpdateModel` is called on `person` rather than `viewModel`. I've already fetched `person` from the database, so it's completely filled out, with an Id. The `TryModelUpdate` method uses an `IModelBinder` to map properties from the current "mvc request context" to the specified object. Since my `PersonModel` and `EditPersonNameModel` use the same named properties, it works. This is really a very poor solution, so if you know of something better, please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) or similar solution, there is no built-in support for model->model mapping in mvc 3.

Comment: AutoMapper doesn't seem to work. I'll edit my post with some examples.

Comment: I've posted my new code. If either of you know a way to get AutoMapper to work, that would be great!

Comment: `Mapper.Map` accepts also two objects - source and destination so you can do just `Mapper.Map(viewModel, person)` and it will use `person` instance as destination.

Comment: Okay, it was obviously very late when I edited my post. I should have noticed that second argument to `Map`! :) That works! I'd still like to know if there's a better way to do this than how I'm doing it, but I'm going to close this question and will ask another, more precise question for that.